# symbol if cannot determine type

Tags: python, types, if-statement

**Lab instructions**:  create a loop that will iterate a total of 10 times using the value of a variable that is incremented by one each time the loop completes.  Upon each iteration of the loop print a message indicating how many times the loop has run. For example the message could read: ”The loop has run ‘x’ times” The ‘x’ will be replaced by the value of the loop control variable.  When the loop has completed 10 iterations print a message that the loop is finished.

I have created a flowchart using Raptor that executed successfully.  It is here:  http://fs1.hidemyass.com/img/RpAbF.jpg

I have to write a program with Python that does the same thing as the flowchart.  I am getting an error when I try to run the prog.

```
num=raw_input ("Please enter a number.")
counter = 1

if counter = 11:
    print ("The loop is now complete!")
else:
    print ("The loop has run " + counter + " time(s)")
    counter = counter + 1
```

It says "Symbol:if cannot determine type"

Comment: I should note though that Python would throw a different exception...`if cannot determine type` is not coming from any Python I know. Are you perhaps running it in some other interpreter?

Comment: @tripleee [Homework tag is blacklisted now](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag)

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `==` when comparing values:

```
if counter == 11:
```

Answer (score 0):

`=` is used to assign a value to a variable. `==` is used to test two expressions for equality.

Side-note: Where the the loop in your code? Consider using a `for` loop: [docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html)

```
for i in range(1,11):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: I seem to have figured it out. I used a while loop instead and it works.  New code:

    num=raw_input ("Please enter a number.")
    counter = 1

    while (counter < 10):
        counter = counter + 1
        print("The loop has run " + str(counter) + " time(s)")
    else:
        print ("The loop is now complete!")